# Flushing tx udp socket kernel buffers to reduce latency

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, latency

I have a Linux based wireless network application which requires to be pretty hard on latency. i.e., late arrival of a data packet is no better at all compared to no data. Also, Old data in the socket can only delay the newer data.

I'm looking if from the transmit side there is any way to detect that the socket is piling up with old data and in such case flush/discard it and send fresh data.

I know the receiver can read all of the old data and discard. However, this will still play catch up and not really help in speeding up as well as if there was a sender side option to evaluate.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The kernel already transmits data out of the send buffer as fast as possible, and the network will already drop it when necessary.

Comment: @EJP, thanks! While yes, there's an attempt to send the buffer ASAP, in a scenario while there is a disconnect and reconnect, kernel will send old data first and potentially dropped/accumulated packets in the application space and then start with the new data. I was hoping there would be a way to jump to the new data by flushing out the old data completely.

Comment: Currently we use debugfs to read the tx queue and based on a set upper threshold, we don't not add more data to the queue and wait until the tx queue hits a low watermark before putting in new data to prevent continued loading of old data into the stream. We need to find a way to just discard the tx queue if it hits the upper threshold and immediately hit the bottom of the queue.

Answer (score -1):

Try turning off the Nagle algorithm on the sending side. This algorithm tries to collect smaller packets into larger ones to reduce overhead, so turning it off can mean each packet is sent immediately. Here's a code snippet to turn it off:

```
void noNagle (int socket)
{
        int on = 1;
        if (setsockopt (socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0)
            bye ("Can not disable nagle algorithm\n");
}
```

Comment: The Nagle algorithm is part of TCP, not UDP.